# Translator Text API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

We are asked to propose a solution for translating customer content from European language to English and vise versa, strictly submitted data should not be stored because our data is classified as confidential, hence looking for a API that does not store submitted data.

I came across Microsoft Translator API Text, but not clear about the Terms and Conditions.  Please clarify below queries.

1. Does customer data stored if we use Microsoft Translator API Text while transferring the information?
2. If the data store, will it be in Microsoft private cloud or in customers tenant/subscription?
3. What the policy for document content translation?

Comment: I would recommend engaging directly with Microsoft support for questions like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customer data submitted for translation through the Microsoft Translator Text API and the text translation features in Microsoft Office products are not written to persistent storage. There will be no record of the submitted text, or portion thereof, in any Microsoft data center. The text will not be used for training purposes either. Learn more about no-trace here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/notrace.aspx.

Best regards,
Gwenda
Microsoft Translator Team